# Программы взлома соцсетей

Tags: взлом, соцсети

Добрый день!
Мне вот интересна такая тема, доступны ли широкой общественности программы по взлому страничек пользователей разных социальных сетей (Вконтакт, одноклассники, фейсбук и другие) или это миф очередной? Почему-то вызывают сомнение, что такой продукт программный можно найти на просторах Интернета.
Одна девушка мне сказала, что она взламывает программами специальными вконтакт и одноклассники. На мой взгляд, это маловероятно, чтобы человек без образования компьютерного мог это сделать. Для интереса скачивал пару таких программ, якобы взламывающих страницы, и не обнаружил ничего хорошего, кроме обмана: имитация взлома, спам, смс-подтверждение для распаковки программы и прочая чушь. И потом взлом в большинстве случаев происходит якобы по перебору возможных паролей (взлом "ломом"), что социальная сеть просто бы такое количество попыток входа в аккаунт отвергла бы. И второй нюанс - на такой  взлом ушло бы много времени, а не то, что пишут в программах прогнозируемое точное время взлома в районе 15 минут.
Что скажете по этому поводу, есть ли ПО взлома соцсетей или это просто обманка для дураков?) Второй вопрос: каким же образом осуществляют реальные взломы (мысли сразу о xss-атаках и уязвимостях) социальных страниц пользователей?

Comment: В общем-то вы сами в своем вопросе довольно убедительно на него ответили.


З.Ы. не "ньюанс", а "нюанс".

Comment: @DreamChild, да, увидел свою опечатку глупую по нюансу), исправил, спасибо. В принципе да, сам опроверг существование таких программ, но второй вопрос остается все же открытым, о типах xss-атаках и способах взлома страниц соцсетей. Непонятно, за что заминусили вопрос, думаю, это полезный вопрос для тех, кто хотел бы пообщаться на тему методов взломов страниц юзеров соцсетей.

Comment: По второму вопросу: мне кажется, во многих случаях большую роль играет легкомысленность пользователей - слабые пароли, доверчивость к сообщениям типа "ваш аккаунт взломан, срочно отправьте смс с новым паролем на этот номер и переведите сто тыщ миллионов денег в фон помощи бездомным котятам, иначе вас съест слон" и прочая так называемая социальная инженерия.

Comment: а что касается 

>Одна девушка, мне сказала, что она взламывает

то есть старый анекдот, когда приходит дед к врачу и жалуется, что у него с женой давно ничего не получается.Тот его спращивает, а сколько же тебе, деда, лет? Дед говорит, что 75. Врач ему отвечает: "А что вы хотите, возраст все-таки". Дед возражает: "А вот моему соседу 77, и он говорит, что он со своей бабкой аж по два раза на дню". Врач просит деда показать язык, после чего говорит: "Язык у вас здороывый, можете говорить то же самое"

Comment: Плюс еще маленький аргумент - если б каждый дурак действительно мог ломать чужие аккаунты за 15 минут, то все фейсбуки давным-давно бы обанкротились. Но они еще вроде живы.

Comment: @DreamChild, согласен, что верить на слово людям не стоит, особенно тем, кто далек от ИТ-сферы, тем не менее я действую чаще методом перепроверки самолично...

Comment: Читал про скандал, когда у владельца увели крупный паблик ВК, использовав коррумпированного друга-сотрудника сотового оператора: выпускается дубль СИМки на номер владельца аккаунта, далее дело техники.

P.s. оказывается симку увести ещё проще через манипуляции с доверенностями. Это противозаконно и не имеет отношения к программированию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бред. Программ для взлома ВК и Одноклассников нет. Максимум - это всякие вирусы на компьютер жертвы или фейк сайты с авторизацией.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хотелось бы услышать, помимо этого, о реальных способах взлома. На моем счету был взлом только через почтовый ящик, через который потом я переходил на страницу пользователя вконтакте. Еще были мысли о создании фейк сайта с авторизацией, однако для этого надо было сыграть на невнимательности и доверчивости пользователя, что не всегда работает... Что еще предложите в качестве приема взлома?

Comment: @IntegralAL, как вариант, можно отправлять ссылку на авторизацию через API VK и после подтверждения прав, просить ссылку из адресной строки под умным предлогом. Имея токен, творите что хотите. Геморно конечно, но если продумать до мелких мелочей, то ок. К примеру создать сайтик одностраничный, а-ля накрутка лайков и там поэтапно расписать, нажми туда, сюда, вставь то и то.

Можно еще постараться сделать все через приложение ВК. Запросить права нужные (личка, стена и т.д) и просто записать токен в базу и работать с ним.

С одноклассниками не помогу, но по сути, та же схема и там сработает.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, что вы должны понимать, но, видимо, не до конца понимаете, если бы такой софт вообще существовал, смысл самого слова "аккаунт" был бы утерян. Не было бы исследователей в области ИБ, не было бы и разнообразных bounty-програм (поощрений) от вендоров. Да и смысл тогда какой вообще был бы от самого понятия "Информационная Безопасность"?

Как говорится, "если все герои, то никто не герой", так же и в сфере по защите информации, хакингу, крягингу, кукарекингу (и т.д.) - если кругом одни "хакеры" (хотя они - cracker`ы), то "крутизна" слова сходит на "нет". Мы же пока такого ещё не наблюдаем.

Если уж и находятся однажды какие-либо реально более-менее действенные методы (что-то вроде [CSRF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) или [Heartbleed](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed)), то те, кто отвечают за безопасность программного продукта, стараются фиксить, маскировать, что угодно делать, чтобы уязвимость не только не получила известность у простых юзеров (простых смертных), но и не была широко известна в обществе профессионалов сферы ИБ. Это же авторитет брэнда, как-никак - над дырявым, как правило, только шутят.

---

А так вообще можно, например, написать кейлоггер, встроить в браузер пользовательский скрипт  и много всего другого. Но все это требует хотя бы каких-то знаний, связанных с разработкой как таковой.

Comment: > P.S Без обид, но подобные вопросы могут много сказать( и далеко не самого хорошего ) о его авторе. 

какой же хэшкод без перехода на умственные способности автора, ну право

Comment: Тем не менее, что софта, возможно, такого нету, взломы аккаунтов случаются сплошь и рядом. Есть довольно много людей предлагающих услуги по взлому аккаунтов в соцсетях, которые используют свой талант и навыки для этого. Кража Cookies, кража из форм и множество других способов делают это возможным, думаю Вам все это известно судя по вашей осведомленности в этой области. Наличие софта в форме вирусов, или клиентских программ тоже возможно на мой взгляд. Насчет уязвимостей, то скажу создатели программного продукта порой просто не догадываются о своих багах, которые находят находчивые люди.

Comment: Не то, чтобы я был сторонником черных дел по взлому, или веду какую-то деятельность такого рода. Это просто хобби скорее всего, как часть изучения программирования. Еще в университете мы с товарищем предоставляли друг другу почтовые ящики для того чтобы проверить насколько успешно и быстро мы сможем взломать другу другу их. Тоже самое проводили эксперименты по дешифрованию данных, проверяя прочность алгоритмов шифрования. Так что ничего преступного не вижу в том, чтобы интересоваться такими вопросами и оттачивать навыки в этой сфере.

Comment: @IntegralAL, если и существуют люди, предлагающие услуги по взламыванию аккаунтов, то чем же тогда, вы думаете, занимаются люди, отвечающие за безопасность? Я бы сказал так: в принципе, взломать можно все, что связано со стороной клиента( а это очень много чего ). Ведь помимо программного взлома существуют и такие вещи, как социальная инженерия, которой в той или иной степени подвержены все. Где-то недосмотрел, скачал софт из не очень качественного источника - и все. Доверился знакомому, а тот тебя обманул и т.д. Но со стороны, противоположной клиенту, делается все для защиты конфид.инф-ции.

Comment: ...Иными словами, человеческий фактор будет присутствовать во всех сферах. Как правило, именно он в большинстве случаев и становится роковым. Так что прямого и общедоступного способа удаленного взлома аккаунтов не существует, о чем можно сказать с абсолютной уверенностью..и, честно говоря, хотел бы я быть неправым на этот счет..

Comment: > старался написать так, чтобы никого особо не обидеть. 

Бог мой, это великолепно. Старался намекнуть автору, что я о нем думаю, но так, чтобы он не понял, что я о нем думаю.

Comment: @Etki, мне кажется, тут есть темы поинтереснее, чем та, что вы пытаетесь( видимо? ) развить... Вы уже сказали об этом выше - я удалил. Какие еще вопросы?

Comment: Что касается CSRF, то это далеко не единственный действенный способ, можете почитать по этому поводу информацию, если считаете меня неправым в этом вопросе. Возможно, я дилетант в вопросах хакерства и информационной безопасности, тем не менее даже я могу сказать про DDoS-атаки, XSS-червей, а также пассивные методы выманивания нужной информации у пользователя. Скажете, что XSS-червь - это не софт или программа? Тогда что это, по вашему? Умственные способности тут ни при чем, я с красным дипломом окончил московский вуз, тут, скорее, дело в осведомленности в этой сфере, в чем я еще не преуспел..

Comment: @IntegralAL, не совсем понял, что вы хотели сказать своим последним комментарием..

Answer (score 0):

У меня один раз увели пароль от аккаунта. Каким-то образом сменили DNS. И запустили проксирование через свой сервак. А контакт тогда просто по http работал. Как произошла смена DNS, для меня до сих пор отстаётся загадкой. Но варианта взлома два, и оба не простые.

1. Атакуем компьютер жертвы и сливаем пароль.
2. Перебираем через api пароль с большим интервалом времени, чтобы не заблочили ip (жизни наверное не хватит).

Comment: Странно. Вы не обратили внимание на несоответствие сертификата? Браузер должен был возмущаться.

Comment: > Каким-то образом сменили DNS. И запустили проксирование через свой сервак
Может .hosts подменили? :) Учетка наверное админская? ;) (лишь предположение)

Comment: @cyberdream, нет. Именно в настройках сетевой карты были прописаны левые ДНС. Т.е., открывая vk.com, я отправлял запрос на фейковый сервер, который через прокси отдавал мне вк, но анализировал трафик.

Answer (score 0):

Это - "ПО"  - развлечение школьников младшего возраста.

Десятки, а то и сотни людей с огромным багажом знаний разрабатывают механизмы защиты, шифровки.

Ну, в принципе, этакий взлом - не миф, но это распространенные способы - стиллеры, брутфорс, кейлоггинг, НО:

1. Для первого нужно еще заразить компьютер жертвы, что достаточно проблематично выйдет.
2. Второй вариант использовать на получение доступа к определенному аккаунту - бессмысленно, могут и сотни лет уйти на подбор, не считая человеческого фактора, как пример - частой смены паролей.
3. С кейлоггерами та же  песня, что и со стиллерами.

Да и тут тоже куча своих "подводных камней", таких как социальная инженерия.

А по поводу программ, "дающих доступ к аккаунту в один клик", стоит просто голову включить - такие инструменты должны иметь прямой доступ к базам данных, знать "соль", используемую для хранение данных, что уже глупо - никто не даст такой информации в открытый доступ.

В общем, выкиньте эту мысль из головы. Такого не существует.